# Apply function to each element of list and rename

Tags: python, list

I would like to run two separate loops on df. In the first step, I would like to filter the df by sex (male, female) and year (yrs 2008:2013) and save these dataframes in a list. In the second step, I would like to do some kind of analysis to each element of the list and name the output based on which sex & year combination it came from.

I realize I can do this in one step, but my actual code and significantly more complex and throws an error, which stops the loop and it never advances to the second stage. consequently, I need to   break it up into two steps. This is what I have so far. I would like to ask for help on the second stage. How do I run the make_graph function on each element of the list and name it according to sex&year combination?

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_toy=pd.DataFrame([])

df_toy['value'] = np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=100000)
df_toy['age'] = np.random.choice(range(0, 92), 100000)
df_toy['sex'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100000)
df_toy['year'] = np.random.randint(low=2008, high=2013, size=100000)

def format_data(df_toy, SEX, YEAR):
    df_toy = df_toy[(df_toy["sex"] == SEX) & (df_toy["year"] == YEAR) ]
    return df_toy

def make_graph(df_):
    plt.scatter(age, value) 
    return df_toy
dfs = []

for SEX in range(0,3):
    for YEAR in range(2008,2014):
        dfs.append(format_data(df_toy, SEX, YEAR))
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    df_=dfs[i]
    make_graph(df_)
    df_YEAR_SEX=df_
```

Comment: I don't understand `make_graph`. You pass a variable `df_ `which is not used; use `age` and `value` which are not defined and for some reason return a global `df_toy` which is not then used,

Comment: df_ is not a variable, but an element in dfs list, which is created in the second loop. See df_=dfs[i] ... But I get your point. I don't exactly know what to reference in the function make_graph because he dataframe that should be referenced, has not been created at that point. Should it be def make_graph(age, value) without a reference to the dataframe used?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could filter plot and save the data like this. Since I don't know the actual data I don't know why you need to do it in 2 steps, here is how you could do it with a few changes.

```
# Input data
df_toy = pd.DataFrame({
    'value' : np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=100000),
    'age' : np.random.choice(range(0, 92), 100000),
    'sex' : np.random.choice([0, 1], 100000),
    'year' : np.random.randint(low=2008, high=2013, size=100000)
})

def filter_and_plot(df, SEX, YEAR):
    # filter the df for sex and year
    tmp = df[(df["sex"] == SEX) & (df["year"] == YEAR)]

    # create a new plot for each filtered df and plot it
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x=tmp['age'], y=tmp['value'], s=0.4)

    # return the filtered df
    return tmp

result_dict = {}
for SEX in range(0,2):
    for YEAR in range(2008, 2013):
        # use a f-string to build a key in a dictionary which includes sex and year
        # keys look like this: "df_1_2009", the value to each key is the filtered dataframe
        result_dict[f"df_{SEX}_{YEAR}"] = filter_and_plot(df_toy, SEX, YEAR)
```